# Swift CGPoint Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, swift3

```
private var sockets: [CGPoint] {
    let buttonSize = button.bounds.size
    let rect = view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 4 + buttonSize.width / 2, dy: 4 + buttonSize.height / 2)
    let sockets: [CGPoint] = [
        CGPoint(rect.minX, rect.maxY),
        CGPoint(rect.minX, rect.maxY),
        CGPoint(rect.maxX, rect.minY),
        CGPoint(rect.maxX, rect.maxY),
        CGPoint(rect.midX, rect.midY)
    ]
    return sockets
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

on the first `CGPoint(rect.minX, rect.maxY)`. I think this is an issue updating from Swift 2 to Swift 3.

Comment: Did you lookup the reference https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgpoint or tried autocompletion?

Comment: Voting to close this question as a typo.

Comment: @JAL I disagree with this being a typo. Just now I had 3 CGPoints in an `addCurve(to:control1:control2:transform:)`. I was getting this error. I thought I was using `addCurve` wrong not CGPoint. I'm still in disbelief that CGPoint init parameter labels are not underbarred. I mean `CGPoint(2,13)` looks so much better! What were framework authors thinking? My point is, I'm seeing this as a common mistake from those of us used to `CGPointMake` in C.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the documentation for `CGPoint`. You need to specify the `x` and `y` argument labels:

```
CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.MaxY)
```